# PL/SQL add 7 days to datetime and get something between that date

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql

Ok, so i have database on PL/SQL.

Here is my sql question:

```
SELECT t.AC_NUMBER, t.DATE, a.comment_1, a.comment_2, a.comment_3, a.comment_4
  FROM proddba.cust_info t
       left join proddba.cust_descr a on a.ac_number=t.ac_number
 where a.open_date=(select min(b.open_date) 
                      from proddba.cust_descr b 
                     where b.ac_number=t.ac_number 
                       and b.open_date>=t.date 
                       and b.open_dane<=t.date+7days)
```

How to dynamically add +7 days to date?

And second, how to get only one date `min(b.open_date)` if there is two this same datas? Should I use **distinct**?

```
(select distinct min(b.open_date) 
   from proddba.cust_descr b 
  where b.ac_number=t.ac_number 
    and b.open_date>=t.date 
    and b.open_dane<=t.date+7days)
```

If have to get about 15000 records from database, is this should work?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a number of days to a `DATE`

```
t.date + 7
```

will add exactly 7 days to the `DATE` in `t.date` (so the time component will be preserved).

`MIN` will already cause the subquery to return a single data value-- there is no need to add a `DISTINCT` since it won't ever change the output.  I'm not sure what problem you are trying to describe that results from getting multiple rows-- are you possibly concerned that the outer query returns two rows that have the same `a.open_date` value and you are trying to ensure that you get only one row?

Comment: t.date + 7 won't work. "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER"

Comment: @breq - That implies that either `t.date` or `b.open_dane` (is that really `open_dane` rather than `open_date`) is not defined as a `DATE`.  Which of these are defined as a `NUMBER`?  And how do you convert that `NUMBER` to a `DATE`?

Comment: your date column is a varchar type, convert it to date using to_date, supplying appropriate date format, updated code should look like to_date(t.date,'DD/MM/YYYY') + 7;